# Latex isn't displayed since a few months (Firefox on Linux), what does Latex need to be displayed?

Tags: support

It's been a few months Latex is not displayed anymore on my Firefox on Linux. It's still displayed on Wikipedia and many other websites though, only Physics Stack Exchange (and a Physics forum) seem to have this problem. I do have some extensions, but even when I disable all of them, Latex is still not displayed. So I do have javascript enabled. I'm wondering what I need to enable (in about:config I suppose) to make Latex work here. Any idea what could be the culprit?

Comment: What version/flavor of Linux?

Comment: @KyleKanos Arch Linux. (Both on my laptop and desktop pc).

Comment: Okay. I have no issues on Linux Mint 18.

Comment: Did this start last month? If so it could be related to the [MathJax CDN switch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294710/56541).

Comment: @DavidZ Unfortunately I don't remember that well when I first faced the problem. In my mind it's about 2 months though, but the "error bars" are huge.

Comment: @DavidZ I followed your link and allowed javascript from cloudfare.com, which seems to have fixed the problem. I don't understand how come disabling noscript add-on didn't fix the problem previously. I had tried at least 3 times, on 2 different machines, and I'm sure that disabling noscript did not fix the problem. Anyway problem solved!

Comment: @DavidZ Maybe post it as an answer and tag status-completed?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Sure, answer posted - I was waiting to see whether that was the issue. No need for a status tag though IMO, since those are meant for bug reports and feature requests, and generally issues that require some kind of direct moderator or community action to resolve.

Comment: With firefox, you can also view the network traffic of a full page load with its builtin debugger tool. So, you can see, what is going on, which requests couldn't executed, the javascript error console and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related to the [MathJax CDN switch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/294710/56541), which occurred last month. If so, you'll have to make sure `cdnjs.cloudflare.com` is whitelisted in any script blocker you may be using, and you might as well clear the browser cache while you're at it too. (I don't know how that could really help, but it can't hurt.)